# Using NIntegrate with a combined separable function

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the function

```
w[x, t] = p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t] + p3[x]*u3[t] + ....
```

where `p1[x]`, `p2[x]` and `p3[x]` are known.

My problem is in using `NIntegrate` with

```
NIntegrate[w[x, t]*p1[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This does not work because there is the function `u[t]`. Is there any way to separate `u[t]` from each term before integration and then multiply them after preforming the integral? Or can I do `NIntegrate` with `u[t]` inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows. Here is your expression to be integrated:

```
w[x, t] = p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t] + p3[x]*u3[t];
```

Assume that you need to integrate over x from 0 to 1. Then this makes the job:

```
w[x, t] /. u_[x]*v_[t] :> v[t]*NIntegrate[u[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

yielding the following answer:

```
(*  NIntegrate[p1[x], {x, 0, 1}] u1[t] + 
 NIntegrate[p2[x], {x, 0, 1}] u2[t] + 
 NIntegrate[p3[x], {x, 0, 1}] u3[t]   *)
```

If you do not fix the functions `pi[x]` there will be also warnings, they should disappear as soon as Mma "knows" these functions.

**Later edit**: The author commented that it does not work in the following case:

```
p1[x_] := -Cos[4.7300407 x] + Cosh[4.7300407` x] + 
  0.9825022 Sin[4.7300407 x] - 0.9825022 Sinh[4.7300407 x]; 
p2[x_] := -Cos[7.8532046 x] + Cosh[7.8532046 x] - 
  1.0007773 (-Sin[7.8532046 x] + Sinh[7.8532046 x]);
```

Indeed, after the substitution of the rule the result is wrong, and I do not see, why.

One can go another way around, much more simple which is possible, if one has fixed the functions p1[x] and p2[x]. Namely,

```
 w[x_, t_] := p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t];
Integrate[w[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]

(*  0.830862 u1[t] + 1.94833*10^-6 u2[t]  *)
```

**Second edit** to address your last question

OK, if you strongly need `NIntegrate` to accelerate the calculation, the following can be done. Let me first redefine the functions to include such that your mentioned in your question:

```
p1[x_] := -Cos[4.7300407 x] + Cosh[4.7300407` x] + 
   0.9825022 Sin[4.7300407 x] - 0.9825022 Sinh[4.7300407 x];
p2[x_] := -Cos[7.8532046 x] + Cosh[7.8532046 x] - 
   1.0007773 (-Sin[7.8532046 x] + Sinh[7.8532046 x]);
p3[x_] := p1[x]^3*p2[x]^4;

w[x_, t_] := p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t] + p3[x]*u3[t];
```

You are right that using simply `Integrate[w[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]` takes too much time, which is unacceptable. Using `NIntegrate[w[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]` instead is impossible.
Let us try this:

```
Plus @@ Table[NIntegrate[Drop[w[x, t][[i]], -1], {x, 0, 1}]*
    Last[w[x, t][[i]]], {i, 1, Length[w[x, t]]}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {4.98792, 0.830862 u1[t] + 1.94833*10^-6 u2[t] + 2.15982 u3[t]}  *)
```

which takes 5 seconds. I hope that's better.

Have fun!

Comment: in this step:
w[x, t] /. u_[x]*v_[t] :> v[t]*NIntegrate[u[x], {x, 0, 1}]

why did you change the pi[x] to u[x] and u[t] to v[t] ?
cant i use the same names? also can you give what does the code means ?

Comment: @Love Eva This belongs to basic structures of the Wolfram Language.  Have a look here http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/patterns/ as well as Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/guide/Patterns There you will find some more information on it. I can also recommend to read the corresponding section of the book of Leonid Shifrin which you can get here http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/ for free.

Comment: is there any way to define this as rule? because w[x,t] is repeated many times and each time i should do NIntegrate.

Comment: @Love Eva It is a rule. But you may, of course write: `rule=u_[x]*v_[t] :> v[t]*NIntegrate[u[x], {x, 0, 1}]`. and use it everywhere.

Comment: for some reason its not working:
(*rule*)
rule2 = u_[x]*v_[t] :> v[t]*NIntegrate[u[x], {x, 0, 1}];

(*functions*)
p1[x] = -Cos[4.7300407 x] + Cosh[4.7300407` x] + 
   0.9825022 Sin[4.7300407 x] - 0.9825022 Sinh[4.7300407 x];
p2[x] = -Cos[7.8532046 x] + Cosh[7.8532046 x] - 
   1.0007773 (-Sin[7.8532046 x] + Sinh[7.8532046 x]);

w[x, t] = p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t];
 
w[x, t] /. rule2

(-Cos[4.73004 x] + Cosh[4.73004 x] + 0.982502 Sin[4.73004 x] - 
    0.982502 Sinh[4.73004 x]) u1[
   t] + (-Cos[7.8532 x] + Cosh[7.8532 x] - 
    1.00078 (-Sin[7.8532 x] + Sinh[7.8532 x])) u2[t]

Comment: @Love Eva  Yes, you are right. I cannot understand, why is it like that. Please have a look at the edit.

Comment: what is edit ? (*im new*) :)

Comment: @Love Eva  It is something I added to the text of my answer above. It is marked by a bold font.

Comment: Sure the Integrate command gonna work fine, but the problem some time i have p1[x]^3*p2[x]^4 in this case it will take more than 15 min to done. moreover i have in total of 30 similar equation, it means it will take days to give the final result, that's why NIntegrate is much faster and more accurate in the result. Finally, in other cases i have up to p5[x], so :(.

Comment: @Love Eva  Have a look at the second edit.

Comment: the second edit is really helpful, but why there is constant generated? 
if im using 
w[x_, t_] := p1[x]*u1[t] + p2[x]*u2[t];
i should only get 
0.830862 u1[t] + 1.94833*10^-6 u2[t]

Comment: @Love Eva What constant?

Comment: 4.98792 which appear  {4.98792, 0.830862 u1[t] + 1.94833*10^-6 u2[t] }

Comment: @ Love Eva This is time in seconds. You might have, at least, yourself looked into Help to see what is `AbsoluteTiming". Remove this function and you get what you want.

Comment: i reached the point where i need to use (p1[x]+p2[x]+p3[x])^2(w[x,t])^3. i tried to yous the edit 2 but it did not work. can you pleas help in that ?